# Reshape the dataframe with keeping unique values in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have question, how to remove duplicate values for a single timestamp.
I have a big data having millions of rows.
This is how my sample dataframe with problem looks like:

```
     Name <-c('PP_1','PP_1','PP_1','PP_1','PP_1')
     category<-c('GT','GT','GT','GT','GT')
     year<-c('2025','2025','2025','2025','2025')
     month<-c('12','12','12','12','12')
     day <-c('30','30','30','30','30')
     period<-c('1','1','1','1','1')
     value<-c('53.55','0.00','0.00','0.00','0.00')
     df<-data.frame(Name,category,year,month,day,period,value)
     df<-transform(df, Name = as.character(Name),category =  as.character(category),year = as.integer(year),
          month = as.integer(month),day = as.integer(day),period = as.numeric(period),value = as.numeric(value))
```

How can I get rid of these unwanted multiple value (here zeros) for the same timetsamp? Like, I would like to keep highest value e.g. '53.55' and remove all zeros for the same time period
The final df supposed to be looked like

```
Name <-c('PP_1')
 category<-c('GT')
 year<-c('2025')
 month<-c('12')
 day <-c('30')
 period<-c('1')
 value<-c('53.55')
 df<-data.frame(Name,category,year,month,day,period,value)
```

There are multiple `Names` in dataframe and `values` for the entire year and when I use `reshape_df<- tidyr::spread(df,Name,value)` it gives me `Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 1032 rows` . I was trying with `df%>% gather(Name,year, month, day, period, value)` function but no luck. Could someone help me to get the correct solution?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming `value` is actual number  and not string as shared in the example you can use `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% slice(which.max(value))` using `dplyr` to get row with maximum `value` for each `Name`.

Comment: Hi Ronak, it keeps ONLY highest values in entire dataframe, like unique `Name`. Solution should consider the rest of values in dataframe for other time periods also. In short each Name shuld give me 8760 values and I have 300 Names. Currently I am having 8764 values (includes these four zeros) for a single Name.

Comment: @M.T. Please add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` into your `data.frame(...)` function.

Comment: Or update to R version 4.0. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `subset`?

```
subset(df, subset=!duplicated(cbind(Name, category, year, month, day, period)))
#  Name category year month day period value
#1 PP_1       GT 2025    12  30      1 53.55
```

This will keep the first record of each combination of the variables specified. If you must use dplyr, then try `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !duplicated(cbind(Name, year, month, day, period)))
```

The definition of "uniqueness" will depend on what variables you put in the filter.

Comment: thanks but gives me error `x[subset & !is.na(subset)] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Comment: Then your sample data is not similar to your real data. Can you provide something more realistic to your actual data? Or explain what's different.

Comment: I have changed  the datatypes in main question, could you please see the edited version of dataframe? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(across(-value)) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>%
  filter(value==max(value), .preserve = TRUE)
```

which returns

```r
  Name  category year  month day   period value
  <fct> <fct>    <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
1 PP_1  GT       2025  12    30    1       53.6
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the datatypes of each column in`df` pls check the edited question. I used the solution but says `could't find the function across`. I have library `dplyr` . Any clue ?

Comment: Update to the latest `dplyr` version. `across` is a new function since `dplyr 1.0.0`.

Comment: In older `dplyr` versions you could use `group_by_at(vars(-value))` instead, but I recommend to update.

Comment: @ Martin Gal Thank you very much!